# Building php on compile machine,and run it in alpine failed

Tags: php, linux, docker, makefile, alpine-linux

I've tried to build php7 with the command below:

```sh
./configure --prefix=/root/testphp --with-openssl --enable-zip --enable-mbstring --with-pdo-mysql --enable-static
make
make install
```

And then I try to run it on compile machine, it worked like this:

```sh
[root@guningvm ~]# /root/testphp/bin/php -v
PHP 7.3.4 (cli) (built: Apr  8 2019 11:25:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.4, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

But when I mount the dir `/root/testphp` on an alpine docker container:

```sh
docker run -itd --name "testforphp" -v /root/testphp/:/usr/local/php/ alpine:3.7
```

And run php command in the container with `/usr/local/php/bin/php -v`, it got wrong with `sh: /usr/local/php/bin/php: not found`

Could anyone tell me why it didn't work?I've taken a lot of time with this problem.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to do here. You are building locally and then want to run it in a container?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: I don't think you understand how containers work!  You do everything in the container.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I have built the php locally and then **mount**ed it to the container. In fact, I even copied the whole folder to another dicrectory.

Comment: By the way, my target is to build an image as small as I can.

Comment: I see what you are doing now. If you open a shell in that container, what do you see in the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear, but it seems you are building PHP on your local Linux machine (say, Ubuntu), and trying to run it on an Alpine container.

I'm also assuming you have good reasons for building PHP from source - otherwise, you could use the available [PHP builds for Alpine](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/php7).

Building on non-Alpine Linux and running the resulting executable on Alpine usually won't work, since Alpine Linux uses a special libc (Standard C library) implementation called [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org). musl is not compatible with the GNU C Library - [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc), used by most other Linux distros, so for running native software on Alpine Linux, it must be built against that same, musl libc library.

The `/usr/local/php/bin/php: not found` error message is quite confusing, and assuming the file is present is likely to result from a dynamic linking failure. You could verify that using `ldd /usr/local/php/bin/php`.

Therefore, you'll have to link PHP against the musl C library for running on Alpine, and most preferably, on an Alpine machine.

I can think of the following options:

1. Build PHP on an Alpine container. I'm not sure whether the main development PHP branch supports this (for example, OpenJDK Java Alpine support is developed under seperate projects, named IcedTea and Portola), but it is well worth a try. I believe it is possible, since PHP builds are [available for Alpine](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/php7) - try following their [build recipe](https://build.alpinelinux.org/buildlogs/build-edge-x86_64/community/php7/php7-7.2.17-r0.log), if you encounter difficulties. This is the best option, in my opinion.
2. Keep building PHP on your non-Alpine Linux machine, but link it against the musl libc binary (usually available through packages), instead of glibc. This may be more difficult to achieve, and more prone to issues, so less recommended.
3. Run your built PHP on a glibc-enabled Alpine container. This is a fairly simple procedure. However, this option is probably not a viable one, since your PHP would still be non compatible to vanilla Alpine, and can't be used by PHP Alpine users out-of-the-box. Plus, adding glibc to the container has several MB overhead, which conflicts with your goal for minimal size.

Comment: I finally get it!  He build it in the host OS and wants to run it in the alpine container. That ain't ever gonna work. Hood job thinking this through!

Answer (score 0):

Devils advocate answer:

If your host os was, say, fedora 30 and your container was based on a fedora 30 image, this would work fine.

But then again, we go back to my initial comment about how this isn't the way we use containers.